# Is there a way to have an intent filter only for certain Android versions?

Tags: android

I want to have an `<intent-filter>` only on Android 10+. Is there some way to do that with just adding some attribute to the xml?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not that simple. AFAIK, there is no recipe for doing this with services or receivers, but there is one that should work for activities.

First, create a `boolean` resource, with different values tied to different API levels. For example, you could create a `res/values/bools.xml` file, defining a `boolean` resource, with a name of `isQ`, and a value of `false`. You could then create a `res/values-v29/bools.xml` file, defining another `boolean` resource, with the same name (`isQ`), and a value of `true`.

Then, define an `<activity-alias>` in your manifest, providing an alias for this activity. Put your Android-10-only `<intent-filter>` in the `<activity-alias>`. And, have `android:enabled="@bool/isQ"` on the `<activity-alias>`. This should give you your desired effect: only have that `<intent-filter>` start your activity on Android 10 and higher.

Comment: That is a clever solution, thank you. I'll wait a bit to see if there are other clever solutions before marking it as correct.